# run JavaScript in WebView

Tags: android, webview

i want show my website by webview in Android
But first I want to start webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
((I dont want runJavaScript at first))
and after Page loads completely or after 10sec program webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); automatically
((then I want runJavaScript))
i use  Thread.sleep but didn't work
please help me

this is my code

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);
            String url = "http://student.iaun.ac.ir";
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                                  try {
                                        newActivity();
                                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                             webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                        }
            }).start();    

}

void newActivity() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(15001);

    startActivity(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();   
}

           @Override
           public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
          {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
           }

}
```

Comment: why did you put your `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` in a catch block ? It will not be executed this way. Just move it below the line `newActivity();` in a try block.

Comment: and why do you re-start your own activity ?

Comment: kiruwka:can you write the right code and code that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);
        String url = "http://student.iaun.ac.ir";
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                              try {
                                    startDelay();
                                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                    }
        }).start();    

}

void startDelay() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

All I did was move the setJavaScriptEnabled call into the try portion of your try catch, and I removed the call to startActivity since it didn't make sense to me to restart the whole activity after 10 seconds.

Better than this though, set a `WebViewClient` and in the OnPageFinished method put `setJavaScripteEnabled(true)`.

Comment: @user3033953 glad to help, don't forget to mark this answer as correct/upvote it if it works for you.